# Is there any known method to simulate a UTM with an instance family of the three body problem in physics?

Tags: turing-machines, physics

I think it would be challenging since the three body problem is about continuous movement and Turing machines execute in discrete steps.

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43181/is-the-unsolvability-of-the-n-body-problem-equivalent-to-the-halting-problem .